# Code error in WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I have created a wcf service but I had some error but could not solve it. 
Over in the IService1.cs, I had the following code.

```
[OperationContract]
List<RecommendPlace> getSearchCoords(string search);

[DataMember]
public string search
{
    get { return strValue1; }
    set { strValue1 = value; }
}

public List<RecommendPlace> getSearchCoords(string search)
{
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/basicSearch?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&searchVal=" + search + "&returnGeom=1");
    myRequest.Method = "GET";
    WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    myResponse.Close();
    string coords;
    bool check = true;
    JObject doc = JObject.Parse(@result);

    using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(result)))
    {
        while (jsonReader.Read())
        {
            if ((string)jsonReader.Value == "ErrorMessage")
            {
                check = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if (check)
    {
        coords = result;
    }
    else
    {
        coords = "error";
    }
    return coords;
}
```

Over in the Service1.svc.cs is this:

```
public List<RecommendPlace> getSearchPlace(string search)
{
    RecommendPlaceMethods rp = new RecommendPlaceMethods();
    return rp.getSearchCoords(search);
}
```

It can't seems to get the coordinates. Help !

Comment: `I had some error but could not solve it.`

Don't you think it might be pertinent to include the error?

Comment: See reader cotas of message exchange of service and client

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I had this error Error 1 'WcfService1.Service1' does not implement interface member 'WcfService1.IService1.getSearchCoords(string)'

Comment: @Jones can you provide me some links for me to study ? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error Error 1 `'WcfService1.Service1' does not implement interface member 'WcfService1.IService1.getSearchCoords(string)'` tells you exactly what the issue is.  Your class `Service1` does not implement `getSearchCoords(string)`.

In your posted code for `Service1.svc.cs` you have

```
public List<RecommendPlace> getSearchPlace(string search)
```

But in `IService1.cs` you have:

```
[OperationContract]
List<RecommendPlace> getSearchCoords(string search);
```

`getSearchPlace` is not the same as `getSearchCoords`.

Also, why do you have a `[DataMember]` in your interface (`IService1`) and a method implementation?  There should be no implementations **in** your interface, just definitions.  The class implementing the interface is responsible for the logic in the methods and/or properties.

It should look something like this:

*IService1.cs*

```
namespace WcfService1
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        List<RecommendPlace> getSearchCoords(string search);
    }
}
```

*Service1.svc.cs*

```
namespace WcfService1
{

    public class Service1 : IService1
    {

        public List<RecommendPlace> getSearchCoords(string search)
        {

            HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.onemap.sg/API/services.svc/basicSearch?token=qo/s2TnSUmfLz+32CvLC4RMVkzEFYjxqyti1KhByvEacEdMWBpCuSSQ+IFRT84QjGPBCuz/cBom8PfSm3GjEsGc8PkdEEOEr&searchVal=" + search + "&returnGeom=1");
            myRequest.Method = "GET";
            WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
            string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            myResponse.Close();
            string coords;
            bool check = true;
            JObject doc = JObject.Parse(@result);

            using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(result)))
            {
                while (jsonReader.Read())
                {
                    if ((string)jsonReader.Value == "ErrorMessage")
                    {
                        check = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (check)
            {
                coords = result;
            }
            else
            {
                coords = "error";
            }
            return coords;
        }
    }
}
```